# make a mirror of the extended display in the primary display

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I know this sounds ridiculous, but is there a way I can create some kind of window to view what is being displayed on a second montitor that is extended from the primary view?

In the end, I'd like to be able to see what is happening on the extended monitor on my main monitor. Any possibilities?

Comment: Open broadcaster or xsplit may be able to screencap it and "preview" it back on the main display.

Comment: @Linef4ult thanks I'll look into those and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Linef4ult looks like open broadcast is a great solution. If you want to post an answer I'll accept. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Comment discussion]

Open Broadcaster(Designed for streaming) can capture screens. Just viewing your captured stream locally gives a window into the second monitor.

In theory this could scale to several displays or even other machines but be wary of the performance requirements.